# SSIS CozyRoc SFTP download files modified today

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sftp, ssis-2012

I've got CozyRoc installed for doing SFTP (among other things) on SQL Server 2012.  I'm going to create a job that runs a SSIS package daily.  With this package I want to download from a remote site only those files that have been modified today.  I can't find any documentation on the CozyRoc SFTP task.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found something that works.  In my SSIS package I created a variable called "RemoteFilter".  In that I put this expression:

```
"ModifiedTime >= #" + (dt_wstr,30)(dt_date)(dt_dbdate)dateadd("d", -4, getdate()) + "#"
```

Then in the SFTP task I said the RemoteFilter is a variable, and chose the variable I just created.  I'm sure there's a more elegant and simpler way to do this, but this works.  :)